# How to merge 2 float arrays into 1 array of structs in c

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I wonder if it's possible to merge 2 float arrays into 1 array of structs.

Here's my example code.

```
typedef struct {
    float left;
    float right;
} t_stereo;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    float *leftBuf = (float[4]){1,2,3,4};
    float *rightBuf = (float[4]){5,6,7,8};

    t_stereo *stereo; //how to store *leftBuf and *rightBuf into *stereo?

    return 0;
}
```

So I basically want *stereo to contain data of both *leftBuf and *rightBuf.

I wonder if there's any simple solution to do it.

Comment: Why is malloc and loop not an option?

Comment: The code will be used to process audio buffer. So I'm looking for the fastest possible solution.

Comment: So you do have a slow solution? Show it please. Consider showing it on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ because it sounds like you are off-topic here. Show your code and ask for a speed-focused review.

Comment: That *is* the fastest generic solution. Or have your data pre-interleaved.

Comment: Using malloc and loop is the fastest solution?

Comment: for further optimization you need to use system-specific features, like SIMD

Comment: What platform is this code supposed to run on? On a typical modern desktop computer anything will probably be fast enough.

Comment: If the size of the array always 4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do. in a nutshell.

```
function toStereo (left, right)

 - loop for each left, right sample.
    - store left sample in left channel, 
    - store right sample in right channel.
 - end loop
```

.

```
typedef struct {
    float left;
    float right;
} t_stereo;

void toStereo(t_stereo* stereoOut, int n, const float* left, const float* right)
{
    // multiplexes left/right channels to stereo buffer
    // n is number of samples
    // assumes stereoOut is not null and points to buffer 
    // that has room for n samples
    while (n--)
    {
        *stereoOut->left = *left++;
        *stereoOut->right = *right++;
        ++stereoOut;
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) 
{
    float *leftBuf = (float[4]){1,2,3,4};
    float *rightBuf = (float[4]){5,6,7,8};

    t_stereo stereo[4];   //will store 4 stereo samples.

    toStereo(stereo, 4, leftBuf, rightBuf);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose the simplest solution is:

```
t_stereo *stereo = malloc(sizeof(t_stereo) * DATALEN);

int i;
for (i = 0; i < DATALEN; i++)
{
    stereo[i].left = leftBuf[i];
    stereo[i].right = rightBuf[i];
}
```

where `DATALEN` defines the length of your buffer